# Desktop showing a battery indicator, computer does not have a battery

Tags: pantheon, desktop-environment, bugs

My computer (desktop PC) has started showing a battery indicator as if it was a laptop. I have tried restarting and checking for system updates to no avail.

[image: Desktop]

It also seems to be confused about how much "battery" there is left.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any device that works with battery (mouse, keyboard, etc.)?
Look at this: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/eitzaf/battery_icon_incorrect_on_a_batteryless_desktop/

Comment: Turns out it was a PS3 controller I had unknowingly plugged in.